# question about next() in arraylist iterator JAVA

Tags: java

I am just wondering what does the highlighted part of the code do here?

```
public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i]; // what exactly does lastRet = i do??
}
```

does lastRet = i assigns i to lastRet?  if so, if i = 3, then we have elementData[lastRet = 3]?
but what does that do? I understand if I have elementData[0] then I am retrieving elementData at the 0 position, and if I have elementData[2] then I am retrieving elementData at the 3rd position.
But what is elementData[lastRet = i]?  is lastRet = i actually checking if lastRet equals to i? like lastRet == i? but if so, why not write lastRet ==i instead?  so it shouldn't be checking equality. So what does lastRet = i do? so it assigns i to lastRet? But then I don't understand what the code: elementData[lastRet = i] do exactly?

Comment: It's setting `lastRet` and then evaluating it.

Comment: Adding `**` to the code is confusing because it's no longer valid.  It would be more clear if you removed the `**` and just left the comment in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an assignment statement is the value being assigned.

In this case the value is just `i` but the statement also has the effect of storing that value in `lastRet`.

Comment: so it has two operations in there? one is first assigning i to lastRet? and then take the operation of elementData[i] for whatever the value of i is? is it correct?

Comment: Yes.  `lastRet` is assigned the value of `i`.  The value of that expression is `i` which is used as the index to the array `elementData`.  It is equivalent to `lastRet = i; elementData[i]`.  Personally, I don't like the syntax `elementData[ lastRet = i ]`.  I would prefer the long version because it is explicit and straightforward.  Someone reading your code may have to stop and think for a moment about what `elementData[ lastRet = i ]` is actually doing.  It's a speed bump to readability. 
 Simple and straightforward is better.  Use 2 lines to do this.

Comment: thank you for the explanations